# How to mock nested methods in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

In order to test my program I need to mock a method call like:

```
entityManager.createQuery("SELECT...", Integer.class).getSingleResult()
```

the `createQuery` part returns a `TypedQuery<Integer>`, but I actually just want to return a single integer: 1.
Currently I am using Mockito in order to create my mocks and I am pretty new to this.

Is there a way of testing this?

Thank you!

Comment: Mock a result, which mocks the result.

Comment: Yes. That's it. Thank you! I thought too complicated on that one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mock nested method calls using mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41732361/mock-nested-method-calls-using-mockito)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have class EntityManager, Query. You can mock your test like below. (mock(), any(), when() ... methods are in Mockito)

```
int result = 1;
Query query = mock(Query.class);
EntityManager entityManager = mock(EntityManager.class);

when(entityManager.createQuery(any(), any()).thenReturn(query);
when(query.getSingleResult()).thenReturn(result);
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Mock the `EntityManager` and then you can pre-define the returning-value. `Mockito.doReturn(1).when(entityManagerMock).createQuery(any(String.class), any());`